# Python return statement in PlotAnimation function

Tags: python, list, animation, matplotlib, return

I have a problem in a function to be used in matplotlib FuncAnimation.

I'm aware this is not 100% related to the PlotAnimation code. It is more related to how `return` works. Anyway, here it go:

I need to plot several lines in the same graph - but I don't know in advance how many lines. So, I created a list of plots (called `lines`) like that:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1), aspect='equal')
lines=[]    
for i in range(len(disc)):
        line, = ax.plot([], [], '-', lw=1.5)
        lines.append(line)
```

Let's say `len(disc)` is equal to or greater than 3. If I do this:

```
def animate(i):
    global disc
    for i in range(len(disc)):
        lines[i].set_data(disc[i].x, disc[i].y)
    return line[0], line[1], line[2]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

All works perfecly (except for the fact that, if `len(disc)` is greated than 3, I miss some of the lines in the plot).

However, I don't know `len(disc)` beforehand. So, my question is: Is there a way to use something like that:

```
return lines
```

(or something like that; I know the above doesn't work), replacing the return statement in the `animate` function above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I can think of is using a for loop

```
   return lines[0:len(lines)]
```

Comment: That should return `lines[0]` only.

Comment: Of course, how stupid. How about `return lines[0:len(lines)]`

Comment: Thank you, return lines[0:len(lines)] worked perfectly!

Comment: @LuizEleno how? `return lines[0:len(lines]` returns a new list with all the elements. So it should be the same, as `return lines` (except for the part, that it produces a new instance).
Btw. `return lines[:]` should be exactly the same.

Comment: @DaveJ Well, I don't know how, it simply worked... I can send you a minimal example, if you want (not this week, though, I'm leaving office today).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if I got this right, as I don't use `matplotlib` myself, but from the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) I got an idea.

1. Why does `return lines` not work? It should be equal to

   ```
   return lines[0], lines[1], ..., lines[len(lines)-1]
   ```
2. Maybe an iterator helps here. The keyword is `yield`:

   ```
   def def animate(i):
       global disc
       for i in range(len(disc)):
           lines[i].set_data(disc[i].x, disc[i].y)
       yield from lines    # in Python 2.x use: yield iter(lines)
   ```

Whereas I don't think, this is the correct/desired way to got, I cannot think of another solution for now.

Do you really need to return something? The documentation doesn't mention a required return-value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it did not work. But the answer from @Amrish Lakhisaran is exactly what I needed.